# Post form data to url in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, umbraco

I'm trying to append data from a form to the Url of my page using Razor (adding a query string). I've done this in ASP.NET Web Controls okay, but I would prefer to do this in Razor if it is possible?

Here's a very basic version of my Razor script but currently the '@test' variable is empty on post:

```
@{
    <form id="test" method="post">
        <input type="text" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    if(IsPost){
        var test = Request.Form["test"];
        Response.Redirect(@Model.Url + "?test=" + @test);
    }
}
```

As a sidenote, is there a way of achieving this without a POST method at all?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve here. Can you expand a little? This looks very messy for something that sounds quite easy.

Comment: are you actually looking for the get method?

Comment: I agree, it does sound easy, but I can't work it out myself. I'm trying to work out how to type something into the text box -> click submit -> append this text box value to the Url

Comment: @mmmoustache I've modified my answer it might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand you want to add input value in your test variable. You should define id for input[text] or you should change it to

**Page:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.GET, null))
{
   <input type='text' name'test' id='test' />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

**or your code**

```
@{
    <form method="get" action="@Model.Url">
        <input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>    
}
```

P.S. I'm not clearly understand your code, because you set POST method and want to process GET method.